# Como colocar um background image no meu ion-content

Tags: css, ionic, sass, background, background-image

Gostaria de adicionar um background image no fundo do meu login

Segue o codigo html da minha login.page.html

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title text-center>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class=”loginPage” scroll=”false”>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Nome</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "nome"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Senha</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)] = "senha"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <ion-button fill="solid" expand="block" color="dark" (click)="login()">Logar</ion-button>
  <ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" color="success" (click)="encaminharRegister()">
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon>
      Fazer cadastro
  </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Codigo do meu login.page.scss

```
page-home{
    ion-content{
        --ion-background: #ffff00 url('../../assets/imagem.png') no-repeat center center / cover !important;
    }
}
```

[image: Segue o estado atual da minha tela de login]

Comment: do login inteiro? no caso para ficar de fundo.

Comment: Sim, queria isso mesmo, porem não consigo, ja tentei dessa forma da foto e tentei uma classe com background-image e nada tambem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo código, eu presumo que a versão que você está usando é o 4 do Ionic.

Sendo assim, para alterar o `background` do `ion-content`, você usa:

```
ion-content {
    --background: #ffff00 url('../../assets/imagem.png') no-repeat center center / cover !important;
}
```

Comment: Realmente é o ionic 4, Muito obrigado! Deu certo.

Comment: Tem algum site para me indicar alem da docs ? muita duvida não é salientada lá kk, a adiçao da imagem deu certo, mais preciso personalizar ela, ajustar ela

Comment: Sobre o Ionic 4, tudo ainda é muito novo, mas eu te recomendo aprender sobre as variáveis do CSS. Para descobrir quais variáveis o componente aceita, abra o Chrome Tools e clique no elemento e vai olhando as variáveis de CSS que ele aceita, e dessa forma, você descobre quais propriedades você consegue alterar. Recomendo também estudar sobre Shadow DOM, coisa que foi adotada pelo Ionic nessa versão para criação dos componentes. Caso queira ver um vídeo, [esse aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSiefccSAB8) explica um pouco das variáveis CSS no Ionic 4.